# Shortest way to update a list of dictionaries in one line

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, functional-programming

Say I have a variable, `people`, which is a list of `person` dictionaries. I want to add a serial number `id` to each dictionary in the list. I could do this:

```py
people = [{'name':'jo'},{'name':'rob'},{'name':'lin'}]
i = 0

def add_id(person):
    global i
    i += 1
    new_person = person
    new_person['id'] = i
    return new_person

people = list(map(add_id, people))
```

But this seems wordy. In other languages, it's a one-liner. Can't I rewrite my `add_id` function as a `lambda` in Python?

Comment: one line if you must: `[person.__setitem__("id", j) for j, person in enumerate(people, start=1)]`. (ab)uses list comprehension.

Comment: @MustafaAydın if we're having fun abusing the language, you could also do `[person.update({'id': idx}) for idx, person in enumerate(people, start=1)]`. Not sure which is more horrible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this need `lambda` or `map`? I feel like you're overcomplicating things.

```
for idx, person in enumerate(people, start=1):
    person['id'] = idx
```

If you're determined to have a one-liner, and you're using python 3.9 or above, there's an interesting solution you could use with the [new union operator](https://towardsdatascience.com/dictionary-union-operators-and-new-string-methods-in-python-3-9-4688b261a417) for dictionaries:

```
people = [(person | {'id': idx}) for idx, person in enumerate(people, start=1)]
```

Be aware that this will cause a `TypeError` for Python 3.8 and lower, though, due to it being an unsupported operation for older versions of Python. As @tobias_k points out in the comments, for python >=3.5 and <=3.8, an alternative one-liner is to use *dictionary unpacking* syntax:

```
people = [{**person, 'id': idx} for idx, person in enumerate(people, start=1)]
```

Comment: Or `{'id': idx, **person}`. (Also, not exactly a syntax error but a type error for unsupported operation)

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't realise you could use unpacking like that. Doing `{'id': idx, **person} ` mucks up the order, though ('id' is inserted at the beginning of the dictionary); if you want it at the end of the dictionary, looks like you can also do `{**person, 'id': idx}`

Answer (score 4):

```
for idx, person in enumerate(people):
    person['id'] = idx
```

Enumerate returns the person and current index in the list which you can then add as a new key. It's not a one-liner but is clean

Answer (score 2):

*Can't I rewrite my add_id function as a lambda in python?*

You can not. As [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) says

> functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain statements or
> annotations.

and [further](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) about assignment statement which mean **assignment is statement**, in your function you use assignment for example

```
new_person['id'] = i
```

therefore your function is not eligible target for converting into lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility without making use of `enumerate`: You could add a parameter `id_provider` to the function and use `itertools.count` as the default. The default is set when the function is declared, so it will assign new and unique IDs whenever it is called, across different collections, and if you want you could still pass a different `id_provider` argument.

```
from itertools import count

def add_id(person, id_provider=count(1)): 
    person["id"] = next(id_provider) 
    return person 

>>> persons = [{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}]                           
>>> [add_id(p) for p in persons]                                           
[{'name': 'foo', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'bar', 'id': 2}]
```

Note that this will change the original persons, though (like your version and most of the solutions provided here). To prevent this, you could copy the `dict` or unpack it into a new `dict`, but not that this is still just a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

```
def add_id(person, id_provider=count(1)): 
    return {"id": next(id_provider), **person} 

>>> persons = [{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}]                           
>>> [add_id(p) for p in persons]                                           
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}]
>>> persons                                                                
[{'name': 'foo'}, {'name': 'bar'}]
```